# Error initialization from incompatible pointer of IOCTL function in Linux kernel 4.8.0-53-generic Linux Mint 64 bit

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, 64-bit, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I've got  an error while writing a char device module, using `Ioctl` command.

```
static struct file_operations my_fops =
{
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl, error is here. I can not fix this.
};
```

Note: please ignore all my `print_k`.

Please, help me fix this. My thanks to all of you.

Here is my code :

```
static long my_ioctl(struct file *f,unsigned int cm,unsigned long arg[b]) 
{  
    int re; 
    unsigned long arg[3];

    switch (cm) 
    { 
        case H_ADD:          

          arg[2] = arg[0] + arg[1];  
          print_k("Driver:Calculating is complete,Result = %d \n",arg[2]); 
        break;  
        case H_SUB: 
          print_k ("Driver: Start ...\n"); 
          arg[2] = arg[0] - arg[1];  
          print_k("Driver:Calculating is complete,Result = %d \n",arg[2]);
        break; 
        case H_MULL:  
          print_k ("Driver: Start ...\n");  
          arg[2] = arg[0] * arg[1]; 
          print_k("Driver:Calculating is complete,Result = %d \n",arg[2]); 
        break; 
        case H_DIV:  
          print_k ("Driver: Start ...\n");  
          arg[2] = arg[0] / arg[1]; 
          print_k("Driver:Calculating is complete,Result = %d \n",arg[2]); 
        break; 
        default:  
          print_k ("Driver: I don't have this operation!\n"); 
        re = -Er; 
        break; 
        }  
    return re; 
} 

static struct file_operations my_fops =
{
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl, 
};
```

Comment: `static long my_ioctl(struct file *f,unsigned int cm,unsigned long arg[b])` is wrong. The last argument must be `unsigned long arg` and not `arg[b]`. If your last argument is designed to be a pointer to some sort of array, you need to cast it *within* your function accordingly.

Comment: I've fixed formatting (to make the code readable)

Comment: Hi @BronislavElizavetin thank you for your answer. I'm sorry about the last argument. That's a mistake. It's  unsigned long arg[], I've made some testings and It works on lower than kernel version 4.8. Unfortunately, It does not work on my own linux kernel version 4.8 -64 bit.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Many thanks.

Comment: @HuyNguyen It's not `arg[]` either. It's simply `arg`. Please find the correct prototype beneath the phrase "`The ioctl driver method has a prototype that differs somewhat from the user-space version`" on the page http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-1

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I am sorry for forgetting your help. Thank you so much !

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin First, I'm sorry for my silly question. But if I replace arg[] to arg, it shows an error :'arg' redeclared as different kind of symbol unsigned long arg[3]. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Oh my goodness, I haven't noticed `unsigned long arg[3];` *inside* the function body. You can't have a variable *inside* function which has the same name as one of the arguments in the function prototype. Please call it differently.

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin It works. Thank you so much !

Comment: @HuyNguyen Shall I make it an answer?

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin yes, please ! Thank you so much.

Comment: @HuyNguyen You're welcome. I appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument `unsigned long arg[b]` in the function prototype is dubious. It should be simply `unsigned long arg` even if it's supposed to be a pointer. It's easy to cast it to the type of interest *within* the function body.

> ..the optional arg argument is passed in the form of an unsigned long, regardless of whether it was given by the user as an integer or a pointer.

( [Linux Device Drivers 3, Chapter 6, Section 1](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-1) )

Also, it's wrong to declare a variable *within* the function body which has the same name as one of the arguments. Please choose another name for `unsigned long arg[3];`.